# ¿Modificar el borde de material input outline?

Tags: html, angular, input, scss, angular-material

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambie el grosor y el color del borde de un material input en mi archivo css

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border: 0.8px solid $color-buttons-secondary-solid-enable !important;
}
```

¿Pero repentinamente aparecio una linea dentro del input, saben que es y como quitarla?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta apuntar unicamente a la clase `.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline` con tus estilos, en tu declaracion estas afectando a varias partes del input por lo que causa esas lineas dentro del contenedor

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: $color-buttons-secondary-solid-enable !important;
}
```